# Creating a 3d roof in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, drawing, fabricjs

I need to make a 3d roof for a project, now the only thing I could come up with is using a library to make a triangle and then put a angled rectangle next to it, to get a 3d effect. Also the height of the triangle/roof needs to be adjustable through textfield where people can fill in the height of their roof.

I used Fabric.js and got a great start, but at this moment my script is bugging out without giving any errors...

[FabricJS drawing image dissapears](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14933747/fabricjs-drawing-image-dissapears)

If anyone has any suggest on which library I could use best, or how to make this program, anything to get me started on this project would really help basically.

Sincerely,
Harmen.

Comment: you should try three.js, it's a simple web gl framework for which you can easily find examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably achieve this with `three.js` should be fairly easy:

http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_geometry_tessellation.html

This shows user input using keyboard:

http://stemkoski.github.com/Three.js/Mesh-Movement.html

and some hello world examples:

http://stemkoski.github.com/Three.js/

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! I was searching the web now for like 3 hours but didn't stumble across this one yet!